# Android: How to open link in chrome without opening in new tab?

Tags: android, google-chrome, kotlin

I have a very simple app that just opens a link in chrome when you open the app. How would I go about not opening a new tab if it's already on the website? I can't think of a way as I can't open chrome without using a URI, which automatically opens a new tab.

[Tangent] I know a shortcut on the homepage would be much better, but this was a request from the boss and our users wouldn't know how to create a shortcut. I've got 50+ endpoints to setup and more every week, if i just have a link to install an app on our website, they can manage that.

[Tangent 2] Ideally, if there is a way to auto create a shortcut or auto set the homepage of chrome by visiting / interacting with a website that would be amazing, but from what I've seen thats not too possible.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("*******************")))
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("*******************")))
    }
}
```

Excuse the garbage code, I don't know much about kotlin/android yet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Custom Tabs instead of opening a browser?

This way you could ensure that the website is only opened once, even when returning to your app.
On the other hand the page would still be run in Chrome.

https://medium.com/google-developers/best-practices-for-custom-tabs-5700e55143ee